# Describe the kernel of the following map

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have some questions on the following problem regarding polynomial factorizations.

**Problem:**

Find the kernal of the map $\phi$ $\mathbb{Z}$[x] -> $\mathbb{R}$ 
where $f(x)$ -> $f(1 + \sqrt{2})$.

**Solution + questions:**

So we are looking for polynomials with coefficients over $\mathbb{Z}$ that have  $1 + \sqrt{2}$ as a root. $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field so we cannot assume the kernel is a principle ideal, though of course the kernel will be some ideal, perhaps it is principle.

The function f = ($x - (1 + \sqrt{2}$))($x - (1- \sqrt{2}$)) is an example of one function that has our desired root with coefficients over the integers, once we compute product: f = $x^2 -2x -1$.

***Question 1: Is the reasoning below correct?***

Now I believe this polynomial is minimal over $\mathbb{Z}$ since the minimal polynomials over the integers are the linear and quadratic polynomials. Hence since polynomial factorizations are unique, the previous form I have written $f$ in would be irreduicble over $\mathbb{R}$ as it is the product of two degree $1$ polynomials. Since the form f = ($x - (1 + \sqrt{2}$))($x - (1- \sqrt{2}$)) is irreducible over R, it is unique, and so there is no further reduction possible over $\mathbb{Z}$ from the listed quadratic.

Next since the kernal, $K$, of a homomorphism is an ideal, we know all products of $f$ are contained within $K$.

***Question 2: How to I find the rest of the kernel, $K$?***

Thanks!

Comment: The kernel will be polynomials with $x^2-2x-1$ as a factor. Note in the "split" version you don't have polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ by the constant terms. So your kernel will be the ideal generated by $x^2-2x-1$.

Comment: Also be careful when you say minimal polynomials over the integers are linear and quadratic. Which polynomials produce the $n^{th}$ roots of unity?

Comment: @oshill, so u are saying the kernal is principle here and generated by $x^2 - 2x -1 $?

Comment: Yep since it is the minimal polynomial for $\alpha = 1+\sqrt{2}$. We could try to poke holes, one such would be asking, is this polynomial unique? And yes, minimal polynomials are unique.

Comment: But Z is not a field, so we are not guarenteed Z[x] is a principle integral domain? Or are u using something else?

Comment: @oshill I think you also need the fact that the minimal polynomial splits over $\Bbb Q$, which is true here but won't necessarily be true in general.  See my answer below.

Comment: It is monic, and $x^2-2x-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Then the lemma from Artin: I lost it * one sec

Comment: Ohhh so @oshill since it would generate the kernel over Q being irreducible(and monic) over Q, we can  conclude it must generate that subset of polynomials with integer coefficients. Lemma 11.3.24, if u have the book.

Comment: And its irreducible over Q since 1 + root(2) is irrational right?

Comment: yeah, "Lemma 11.3.24: Let $f$ be a monic integer polynomial, and let $g$ be another integer polynomial. If $f$ divides $g$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then $f$ divides $g$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$" for anyone interested.

Comment: And it looks like the answer below shows a bit of the "why" behind $F[x]$ with $F$ a field yields a unique minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

First, prove (by brute force) that $\psi: \Bbb Q[ \sqrt 2] \to \Bbb Q [\sqrt 2]$ defined by $\psi(a+b \sqrt 2)= a-b \sqrt 2 ~(\text{for } a, b \in \Bbb Q)$ is a field automorphism and note that $\forall a \in \Bbb Q(\psi(a)=a)$.  Thus, $\forall g \in \Bbb Q[x]~\forall \alpha \in \Bbb Q[\sqrt 2], \psi(g(\alpha))=g(\psi(\alpha))$.

Thus, if $f \in \Bbb Z[x] \subseteq \Bbb Q[x]$ satisfies $f(1 + \sqrt 2)=0$, then:

$$0=\psi(0)=\psi(f(1+ \sqrt 2)) = f(\psi(1+ \sqrt 2))=f(1- \sqrt 2),$$ so $1 - \sqrt 2$ must also be a root of $f$, which means that $(x^2-2x-1) \vert f$, so $\ker(\phi) \subseteq \langle x^2-2x-1 \rangle$.  You've already shown that $\langle x^2-2x-1 \rangle \subseteq \ker(\phi)$, so equality follows.